# Declarar clases css con dos puntos, ¿es buena idea?

Tags: css, css3

hasta hace poco he estado diseñando con css con dos puntos (:) y recién ahora
me surgió la duda, ¿Es recomendable hacerlo?

Les dejo un ejemplo de lo que hablo:

```
<style>
.name_clase_css\:otra_clase
</style>
```

Cualquier ayuda, será bien recibida. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Fuera de que la pregunta luce como si fuera basada en opiniones, es un hecho que no es posible realizar lo que pretendes, los 2 puntos (:) son para las pseudo clases `:hover` `:focus` `:active` etc etc, si los llegas a utilizar para declarar clases no funcionaran

Desconozco de donde sacaste la idea tan disparatada, pero Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge no admiten dicha funcionalidad... si ninguno de estos lo admite, para que hacerlo?

Comment: Tailwindcss, declara sus clases de esa manera, no sé si todas, pero las que he usado, se declaran con dos puntos. De ahí que viene la pregunta.

Comment: Tailwindcss hasta donde vi es un pre-procesador como SASS, Stylus o LESS, de ahí que te permita usar los dos puntos como indicas, pero una vez compilado, se convierte en una clase convencional, si tu interés esta en aprenderlo, te recomiendo pasar de largo e ire a SASS, es mas conocido y tendrás mas soporte.